# AWS EC2 FTP / HTML

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I really don't know much about Apache, I followed some tutorials and installed the LAMP stack. I can successfully ftp to /home/ec2-user and upload files there but I want to be able to upload files to the /var/www/html or just have somewhere where I can upload files to the web with my account.

Sorry if my question is not very helpful but I'm not educated enough on servers to provide more information. Ask me questions and I will do my best.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First make sure you can write to the documentroot (/var/www/html in this case)
The default groups for user "ec2-user" on EC2 is "ec2-user" & "wheel"

Either give user "ec2-user" ownership of /var/www/html with the following command

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html
```

Or group "wheel" ownership and write permissions

```
sudo chgrp -R wheel /var/www/html
sudo chmod g+w /var/www/html
```

Second step is to set your FTP client (Filezilla, CyberDuck, ...) to default to /var/www/html
or create a symbolic link in the home directory ec2-user pointing to docroot.

```
ln -s /var/www/html ~/docroot
```

When you authenicate on your ftp client, just doubleclick on what looks like the "docroot" folder.

One caveat is that your DocumentRoot may not be configured as /var/www/html, please check your configurations in /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf labeled with "DocumentRoot".

Comment: For me all I needed was `sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html`. And it solved hours worth of grief for me. Thanks!

Comment: Will this allow user to browse directories or do I need to change something in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: If you mean on the local file system via terminal or ftp client as long as you have read permissions on the file system. If you meant via browser on http request, then you'll need "LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so" uncommented from httpd.conf; this is not advised for most setups

Comment: Connect to Amazon EC2 file directory using Filezilla and SFTP

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful answer, and at the end is a link to a video for Cyberduck.  The text of the Filezilla explanation was enough for me to figure it out for Cyberduck.

[Connect to Amazon EC2 file directory using Filezilla and SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744863/connect-to-amazon-ec2-file-directory-using-filezilla-and-sftp)