# How to Connect EC2 using Cyberduck in straightforward fashion possible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS. I have created EC2 instance. I try to connect Amazon Web Service EC2 file directory using Cyberduck. Anyone one knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find answer for this question.

Open Cyberduck - > Open Connection -> Select [SFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268486/aws-ec2-ftp-html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already done so. I would recommend that you spend a little time becoming familiar with starting [EC2 instances](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1233) manually with the Amazon Management Console (https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home) and connect via Filezilla or Cyberduck